# Pass InputConnection object while starting an Activity

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to start an Activity from a Service and give an extra Parameter in the form of a InputConnention object so I can access it in the Service (maybe somehow with putExtra())?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? dont you think that you have some kind of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Hi, ok @pskink. I want to make a keyboard service which calls an activity and the result of one of the funtions in the activity gets printed out in the chatbox.

Comment: if you start new activity then you cannot make sure that your original activity will not be killed by the system, so everything must be handled by your InputMethodService

Comment: and even if not killed I think the current EditorInfo will be messed up - call getCurrentInputEditorInfo().dump() before calling commitText() to see its content

Comment: Ok thanka. I will check that out.

Comment: oh also by chatbox I mean the normal system output box like when you write a message @pskink

Comment: I have no idea what "system output box" is

Comment: oh sorry. I mean I didnt write a custom editbox where to text gets pasted into. just put out the text into on the chat output im in

Comment: @craft Did you figured it out?